# How to automatically create item number?

Tags: calculated-column, splistitem

Without programming, I need an item number in the following format: `AA-160101-01`

- `AA` is static
- `160 101` is the date,
- `-01` is autoincrementing number, I want to have it counting from 01 every day.

Examples:

The first orders February 1, 2016

- AA-160201-01
- AA-160201-02
- AA-160201-03
- ...
- AA -160201-10

Then on February 2, 2016

- AA-160202-01
- AA-160202-02
- AA-160202-03
- ...
- AA-160202-10
  (restarting from 01)

How can this be done?

Comment: Robert Lindgren, Hello: You are the best I have seen moderators, because I do not know English, translated by Google my problem. I am very worried about Google translation mistakenly describe my problem, but you give me promptly modify very clear. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a helper list when I'm having this requirement.

The helper list has the following columns:

```
Title           | Modified   |Index
-----------------------------------
SomeUniqueTitle | 01.01.2016 | 1
```

When an item is created, a workflow will be started. The workflow checks the Modified date of that specific item in the helper list.

If Modified == Today, take the current value of index and use it in your custom ID, then increment the index by 1.

If Modified != Today, reset the index to 1 and use 1 in your custom ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Ite mAdded event receiver.

Whenever an item will be added your custom code within above event receiver will be excuted.

Steps:-
1.Retreive all list item using query which was created today.
2. If itemCount is 0 ,then there is no item created today ,so assign value to that field for new item using below format

Value=DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy").substring(3)+;DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")+DateTime.Now.ToString("DD")+"01";

3.if itemCount is greater than 0 (today some item has added)then using query get last item ( in list item collection last item will be recently created item)

Retrieve column value of this item, and using substring retrieve last 2 characters which is current date

Convert that to int ,increment one and using above format assign value

Comment: Sure , I will write sample code within 1 hour

Comment: Thank you for your patience to explain, but I am a beginner and sharepoint infopath students, did not say that you can understand how to achieve code. Can I trouble you wrote me some graphic reference it. please. Thank you

Comment: I know you need it , can you wait for Monday for exact code otherwise I just can give instructions here